# What do ext and ext-active subfolders mean in /etc/php?

Tags: php, configuration

On a system I am starting to get acquainted with I see directories named `ext` and `ext-active` in my `/etc/php/cli-php5` directory. I *guess* those are some kind of extension to the default php5 command line interpreter configuration given in

```
/etc/php/cli-php5/php.ini
```

but what do they mean? Are the `php.ini` files in those directories used to overwrite/append extensions of the default configuration? Maybe those are not standard names?

I apologize for this probably trivial question, but a search on the net did not reveal something useful. A simple link to a useful web page would suffice.

Comment: If there are people wanting to close this question, please provide a reason...

Comment: I don't know who voted to close, but the reason given was "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope." So that said, I voted to leave open.

Answer (score 0):

This depends *entirely* on your php.ini base config and what actually happens in quite a few places. Guesswork says that `ext-active` might be containing active PHP extension shared objects... and `php.ini` in the cli directory allows you to override some settings for command-line interface use.

Voting to close as this is too broad, though. It depends on your server's config.

Comment: Thats an answer at least! I was searching for this on google and got hundreds of thousand of hits with `ext-active` and php. So I thought it could be something general. You can close the question if you like.